# Website screenshot python script with parameters

Tags: python

I'd like to start a python project where I would  go to a specific airline's website and run through the booking process for different scenarios. For example:

- Scenario 1 - 1 Passenger, one-way flight, 1 carry-on bag, JFK-LAS, 12/31/2022
- Scenario 2 - 2 Passengers, one-way flight, 1 carry-on bag, JFK-LAS, 12/31/2022

Ideally, I would have the different parameters of the booking path in different columns of an excel workbook which would feed into the python script. In terms of the libraries, I believe BeautifulSoup and Openpyxl are most likely where I should start digging. Are there any other libraries or recommended approaches I should take for this project? Apologies for the very high-level question and please let me know if this question should be posted somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use selenium to go through the site and iterate through different possibilities, then just save the data as a CSV. The CSV will translate directly to an excel file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).